# is this the correct way to test for a posted variables existence?

Tags: php

If a query maybe be optionally run as a `get()` *or* a `post()`, so that `$id = $_POST['id']` maybe get a null value, are any of these a good practice way to test for the possibly posted variable's existence.

`if (!empty($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id'];}else{$id = FALSE;}`

`if (isset($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id'];}else{$id = FALSE;}`

`$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : FALSE;`

or is there some other preferred method? They all do a `$_REQUEST()` twice which inclines me to think there could be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: use `array_key_exists($_POST, 'variable')`.

Comment: Any of them is fine, the last (ternary) is the nicest.

Comment: `isset($_POST)` or `isset($_GET)` to check which method was used

Comment: @YoavKadosh No, better to do `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` to test which was used.

Comment: You'll find all of these in use all over the place.  PHP doesn't have a lot of very nice language constructs like a Ruby or JavaScript conjunction for example: `$id = $_POST['id'] || false` <-- can't do that. They come down to style, but each is correct and common.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can you show me how you would use that in a statement? Thank you.

Comment: @thomas How to use what? The bit in my comment doesn't actually work in PHP. I generally use your 3rd ternary: `$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : FALSE;`

Comment: What if `$_POST['id'] == ''`? Would `isset()` return TRUE?

Comment: @Antony `isset()` returns true for the empty string, yes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So is `strlen()` better to test if a value really exists?

Comment: @Antony Depends what you need. `empty()`  is often more useful, but int 0 or float 0.0 are considered empty. Check out [The definitive guide to isset() and empty()](http://kunststube.net/isset/) by SO member [deceze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I always avoid `empty()` because of that exact reason. I generally use `if (isset($_POST['id']) && strlen($_POST['id']))` to test for the existence of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) && strlen($_POST['id']) > 0 ? (int)$_POST['id'] : FALSE;
```

First it checkes if the var is set, and then check if the length is longer than 0.

In my opinion it is the best readable, as you dont need 5 lines of code if you indent it correctly, what makes it harder to read and makes your file longer:

```
 if (isset($_POST['id'])){ 
   $id = $_POST['id'];
 }else{
   $id = FALSE;
 }
```

And if you use $_POST for a simple thing as an ID, just cast it to an int with (int)$_POST['id']. That way you are sure to have a number.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && strlen($_POST['id'])) $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

to test

- if a value is set (so as not to trigger a notice), and
- if it is an empty string `''`

The issue with `empty()` is that it treats 0 and 0.0 as empty, which can be problematic as the value can sometimes be 0.

The issue with `isset()` alone is that it treats `''` (empty string) as set so if someone happens to submit a form without filling a particular field, `isset()` would let it pass by returning TRUE. `strlen()` is there to check if a value of non-zero length really exists.

Comment: This seems really comprehensive. Just so I'm clear, is there meant to be a semicolon between `strlen($_POST['id']))` and `$id = (int)$_POST['id'];`? Thanks

Comment: @thomas No there isn't. This is a simple `if` statement in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Although all can be used, your first option is the best way to check:

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id'];}else{$id = FALSE;}
```

The following things are considered [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) only checks if it's null.

Comment: aha, yeah, but `id` could be `0`. so I think I'll go with `isset()`. Thanks!

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question! `isset()` would be ideal then.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getByKey($arr, $key, $default = false) {
   return isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $default;
}

$id = getByKey($_POST, 'id');
```

Other way is like

```
   $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => 1, 
            'max_range' => 255,
            'default' => 1,
         )
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a query maybe be optionally run as a get() or a post()

What if it's posted with a query string (so both `$_GET` and `$_POST` contain `id`)?

```
POST /yourscript.php?id=4
Host: yoursite.com

id=3
```

You must choose which `id` to use (this is entirely up to you).

As an alternative to what others are suggesting, you can use PHP's built-in [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php):

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```